# Fatal exception : IllegalStateException Could not execute method of the activity

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, youtube

Here is my MainActivity class where `getUserYouTubeFeed` method is called on clicking a Button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// A reference to our list that will hold the video details
private VideosListView listView;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
}

// This is the XML onClick listener to retreive a users video feed
public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
    // We start a new task that does its work on its own thread
    // We pass in a handler that will be called when the task has finished
    // We also pass in the name of the user we are searching YouTube for
    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "done").run();
}

// This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        populateListWithVideos(msg);
    };
};

/**
 * This method retrieves the Library of videos from the task and passes them to our ListView
 * @param msg
 */
private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
    // Retreive the videos are task found from the data bundle sent back
    Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
    // Because we have created a custom ListView we don't have to worry about setting the adapter in the activity
    // we can just call our custom method with the list of items we want to display
    listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Make sure we null our handler when the activity has stopped
    // because who cares if we get a callback once the activity has stopped? not me!
    responseHandler = null;
    super.onStop();
}
}
```

**Logcat error**

```
08-31 11:34:00.011 27400-27400/com.example.e6530.youtube_playllist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.e6530.youtube_playllist, PID: 27400
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4033)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793)
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19971)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4028)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19971) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                  Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                 at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1168)
                 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
                 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:604)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
                 at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
                 at com.example.e6530.youtube_playllist.GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.run(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.java:54)
                 at com.example.e6530.youtube_playllist.MainActivity.getUserYouTubeFeed(MainActivity.java:37)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4028) 
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4793) 
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19971) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5669) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

In above code, I'm trying to get the playlist videos from Youtube then showing thumbnail & Url in list using android listview. Now I'm getting `IllegalStateException` on the click of button.

Comment: post code of `GetYouTubeUserVideosTask`

Comment: Can you post the code for OnClick button.

Comment: @Raghunandan please check i have uploaded that code too

Comment: @Nirojthapa here is the on click function " getUserYouTubeFeed "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your Task in `AsyncTask`

The exception is due to calling network thread on main ui thread

So execute like

```
     AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // your function calling network thread
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying with Handler Object:

```
 new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "done").run();
```

Try with Async Task Object:

```
 new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "done").execute();
```

**Note : As Network operation will try to run on main thread and already this main thread is used by UI. So avoid running in Mainthread by using async task/intent service.**

For more on [Handler and Async Task Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

For more on [Handler and Async Task Link 2](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.V8aIHF5CaAM)

For more on [Intent Service](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/creating-a-background-service-in-android)